# Is there a R function to get all possible submatrix from a matrix?

Tags: r, tidyr

If I have a matrix like the one below, I would like to group it based on first column and create all combination of submatrix where the number of rows of submatrix will be equal to the number of groups created, as shown in the example. Is there any efficient way to do this in R? I was trying to use tidyverse group_by(), but could not find the correct function to get the submatrix.

```
# Input Matrix
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "1"  "6" 
[2,] "a"  "5"  "9" 
[3,] "c"  "7"  "4" 
[4,] "b"  "5"  "4" 
[5,] "a"  "6"  "4" 
[6,] "b"  "6"  "4" 
[7,] "b"  "4"  "3" 
[8,] "c"  "1"  "2" 
[9,] "d"  "9"  "9" 


# Want to create a Group Matrix
grp1
[1,] "a"  "1"  "6" 
[2,] "a"  "5"  "9" 
[5,] "a"  "6"  "4" 

grp2
[4,] "b"  "5"  "4" 
[6,] "b"  "6"  "4" 
[7,] "b"  "4"  "3" 

grp3
[3,] "c"  "7"  "4" 
[8,] "c"  "1"  "2" 

grp4
[9,] "d"  "9"  "9" 



# Then create - All Combination Submatrix
s1
[1,] "a"  "1"  "6" 
[4,] "b"  "5"  "4" 
[3,] "c"  "7"  "4" 
[9,] "d"  "9"  "9"
s2
[1,] "a"  "1"  "6" 
[6,] "b"  "6"  "4" 
[8,] "c"  "1"  "2" 
[9,] "d"  "9"  "9"
s3
[1,] "a"  "1"  "6" 
[7,] "b"  "4"  "3"
[3,] "c"  "7"  "4"
[9,] "d"  "9"  "9" 

and so on...
```

Comment: the all combination submatrix, how many are you expecting

Comment: actually, all of the combinations that could be obtained based on the number of groups.

Comment: The first case is `split(as.data.frame(m1), m1[,1])`

Comment: Yes, but to get submatrix, is there a function?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with dplyr and purrr.

First, to get the separate dataframes by group, we can use dplyr's `group_split`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

g <- c("a", "a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d")
m1 <- c(1, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6, 4, 1, 9)
m2 <- c(6, 9, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 9)

df <- tibble(g = g, m1 = m1, m2 = m2)

df %>%
  group_split(g)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   g        m1    m2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     6
#> 2 a         5     9
#> 3 a         6     4
#>
#> .......
#>
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   g        m1    m2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 d         9     9
#> 
#> attr(,"ptype")
#> # A tibble: 0 x 3
#> # … with 3 variables: g <chr>, m1 <dbl>, m2 <dbl>
```

To get all row combinations of each group, we'll follow this process:

1. Group by our desired variable (`group_by(g)`)
2. Extract a list of the row numbers where each value of our variable `g` occurs (using dplyr's `group_rows`). The first element of the list will be a list containing the row numbers where g equals "a", the second element where g equals "b", etc.
3. Expand all combinations of the elements of this list using purrr's `cross`. This gives us a list where each element contains the rows for one of the desired submatrices.
4. Subset the matrix with each set of indices, one at a time using purrr's `map`. This leaves us with a list of all possible submatrices, as desired.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>%
  group_rows() %>%
  cross() %>%
  map(., ~df %>% slice(flatten_int(.x)))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   g        m1    m2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     6
#> 2 b         5     4
#> 3 c         7     4
#> 4 d         9     9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   g        m1    m2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         5     9
#> 2 b         5     4
#> 3 c         7     4
#> 4 d         9     9
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   g        m1    m2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         6     4
#> 2 b         5     4
#> 3 c         7     4
#> 4 d         9     9
#>
#> .......
#> 
#> [[18]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   g        m1    m2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         6     4
#> 2 b         4     3
#> 3 c         1     2
#> 4 d         9     9
```

Keep in mind though that the number of submatrices you'll be creating grows as the product of the number of rows in each group in `g` (number of rows in group 'a' times the number of rows in group 'b', times ...).

For example, if you have just 16 groups with 10 rows in each, `cross` will try to create an integer vector of length 10^16. This length is greater than the 52 bit maximum imposed by R and, more pertinently, is far, far greater than your machine can hold in memory - such a vector would require ~37 Petabytes.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the detailed explanation. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: One more clarification, when I try to implement the same approach to a larger matrix, I get the error Error in integer(n) : vector size specified is too large. Can it be over come?

Comment: See the end of the post - I added a bit to address this

Comment: To overcome this vector problem, can I get the submatrix as a combined data frame? Where every submatrix is rbind to form a data.frame. Im trying to get an alternative/efficient way to get this working for larger matrix. Any suggestions?

Comment: Or should I create one sub-matrix at a time and run it through a loop, so that each time I can analyze the submatrix?

Comment: You'll have this same issue in a vector, dataframe or matrix. It would be a very difficult problem to overcome. You could generate the submatrices iteratively so that you wouldn't need to store them all at once, but even then going through that many items will take a very long time computationally.

Comment: To generate submatrix once at at time can I use the group_by() followed by cross()? This would be a one time effort for me, so thinking if submatrix can be tried with loop.

Comment: How many groups do you have, and about how many rows per group? And, what sort of computation do you plan to do with each submatrix?

Comment: The number of groups/rows in groups will vary each time based on certain cut-off I define. Once I get the submatrix I will use it as input for running another program which is pretty quick.

Comment: For example some times I have 30-50 groups and 10-30 rows in each group, then it becomes huge.

Comment: That's a dead end - even the lowest of that range, 10^30 (1 with 30 zeros after it - a million, trillion, trillion) combinations, will be infeasible to compute on. I recommend taking a step back and thinking about if there's another way to approach your problem that won't involve looking at all of these combinations.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting the answer (hit the check mark) if this has solved your question